# Rspec failing for Hartl Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I was working on this earlier today and everything seemd fine, but I went quite a while without running rspec and now I have many a failure.

RSpec results (I scrubbed out my real name and email):

```
Failures:

*deleted, see update below*

7) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should paginate users
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?escape=false&amp;poge=2", :content => "2")
   expected following output to contain a <a href='/users?escape=false&amp;poge=2'>2</a> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | All users</title>
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
   <![endif]--><link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/ie.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]--><link href="/stylesheets/custom.css?1334507400" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header><a href="/"><img alt="Sample App" class="round" src="/images/logo.png?1333923366"></a>
                <nav class="round"><ul>
   <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/users/1">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/users/1/edit">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/signout" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul></nav></header><section class="round"><h1>All users</h1>
   <div class="pagination">
   <span class="previous_page disabled">&larr; Previous</span> <em>1</em> <a rel="next" href="/users?escape=false&amp;page=2">2</a> <a class="next_page" rel="next" href="/users?escape=false&amp;page=2">Next &rarr;</a>
   </div>
   <ul class="users">
   <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/85fb99e31535fbc371865ca9468eae1c?size=30"><a href="/users/1">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/86a7c65390f83bdee8c4455af823b7cb?size=30"><a href="/users/2">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/dd5bff939e78bbc5051efa1a3ff1dcb0?size=30"><a href="/users/3">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/e44c38aa36bffeebb9f59e50de846fb4?size=30"><a href="/users/4">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/125d2f777f0f266ff3fc5e9f79b9b8b7?size=30"><a href="/users/5">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/95a3c1df8f70d065d5f6fe9c799840a9?size=30"><a href="/users/6">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/f41b2a4e646e19853a4396c2d166a078?size=30"><a href="/users/7">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/d31f91433afe441f0cf6ebc9a22aef8d?size=30"><a href="/users/8">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/bb03861fb1123b3afd7e1bb29e9d0b05?size=30"><a href="/users/9">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/c8267a1927445fe261d40a47f53b2ea6?size=30"><a href="/users/10">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/2348e595e0b2331a9d06ed74b309f152?size=30"><a href="/users/11">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/860b2e5e342f55faf0b414f36ab0c948?size=30"><a href="/users/12">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/f4fc0e00abd378811cfa8140be1e1158?size=30"><a href="/users/13">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/fbaf3882d8b938d6e492b7c62a18d3d0?size=30"><a href="/users/14">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/e8c8e9d0376915d55a57fac08ba6e326?size=30"><a href="/users/15">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/65bbf2cc13ab660f9cc879a1308c8a5b?size=30"><a href="/users/16">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/dc892e842ff1fcc90f2e12e111905c70?size=30"><a href="/users/17">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/350c624f4c471c0ea94fe24b3d02fded?size=30"><a href="/users/18">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/4fac89057e3505e044fb8447ab49b0f0?size=30"><a href="/users/19">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/4847c604feadda0992a7be0ed8e000c1?size=30"><a href="/users/20">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/6063db6f5c1108362c76c5a8cd26f046?size=30"><a href="/users/21">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/e4ea822898dad699a636c7efa0418be8?size=30"><a href="/users/22">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/b0be0aebe8cd5972efda62e20e3921ea?size=30"><a href="/users/23">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/3c51b46ac624056903eeae03e52b0c26?size=30"><a href="/users/24">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/40dcd4dfe68e90cf43e34d3f07e5abd0?size=30"><a href="/users/25">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/577e997028169041902deacb43614df2?size=30"><a href="/users/26">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/811db3fdda06d362216f68a0980ee11d?size=30"><a href="/users/27">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/b4c3b9d853242df89ab17ec671c4afe2?size=30"><a href="/users/28">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/49a89d651bd578d6f3646d344c6ad096?size=30"><a href="/users/29">myname</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="myname" class="gravatar" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/044d71640c5ed3504e65bb8f3bb2576c?size=30"><a href="/users/30">myname</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="pagination">
   <span class="previous_page disabled">&larr; Previous</span> <em>1</em> <a rel="next" href="/users?escape=false&amp;page=2">2</a> <a class="next_page" rel="next" href="/users?escape=false&amp;page=2">Next &rarr;</a>
   </div>

            </section><footer><nav class="round"><ul>
   <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Rails Tutorial</a></li>
        </ul></nav></footer>
   </div>
    </body>
   </html>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:161

 *deleted, see update below*
```

Here's users_controller.rb - I'll come back and post the contents of other files if it'll help me.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:show,  :edit, :update]
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
def new
@user = User.new
@title = "Sign up"
end

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@title = @user.name
end

def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
end
end

def edit
@title = "Edit user"
end

def index
@title = "All users"
@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end

def show
@title = User.find(params[:id])
@title = @user.name
end

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
    redirect_to @user
else
    @title = "Edit user"
    render 'edit'
end
end
private
def authenticate
    deny_access unless signed_in?
end

def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
end
end
```

**Update**: I made a correction in users_controller.rb and fixed most of my problems:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) # this was incorrectly written as @title = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
end
```

However, I still have that large HTML error (#7). I attempted to change the line in the spec from `response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2", :content => "2")` to `response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?escape=false&poge=2", :content => "2")` but I am still having the same problem.

Here's the users_controller_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
render_views

describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
        get :new
        response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
        get 'new'
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
    end

    it "should have a name field" do
        get :new
        response.should have_selector("input[name='user[name]'][type='text']")
    end

    it "should have an email field" do
        get :new
        response.should have_selector("input [name='user[email]'][type='text']")
    end

    it "should have a password field" do
        get :new
        response.should have_selector("input [name='user[password]'][type='password']")
    end

    it "should have a password confirmation field" do
        get :new
        response.should have_selector("input [name='user[password_confirmation]'][type='password']")
    end
end

describe "GET 'show'" do
    before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
    end

    it "should be successful" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        response.should be_success
    end

    it "should find the right user" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        puts @user.inspect
        puts assigns(:user).inspect
        assigns(:user).should == @user
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => @user.name)
    end

    it "should include the user's name" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        response.should have_selector("h1", :content => @user.name)
    end

    it "should have a profile image" do
        get :show, :id => @user
        response.should have_selector("h1 > img", :class => "gravatar")
    end
end

describe "POST 'create'" do
    describe "failure" do
        before(:each) do
            @attr = { :name => "", :email => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => ""}
        end

        it "should not create a user" do
            lambda do
                post :create, :user => @attr
            end.should_not change (User, :count)
        end

        it "should have the right title" do
            post :create, :user => @attr
            response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
        end

        it "should render the 'new' page" do
            post :create, :user => @attr
            response.should render_template('new')
        end
    end

    describe "success" do
        before(:each) do
            @attr = {:name => "New User", :email => "user@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar"}
        end

        it "should create a user" do
            lambda do
                post :create, :user => @attr
            end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

        it "should redirect to the user show page" do
            post :create, :user => @attr
            response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
        end

        it "should have a welcome message" do
            post :create, :user => @attr
            flash[:success].should =~ /welcome to the sample app/i
        end

        it "should sign the user in" do
            post :create, :user => @attr
            controller.should be_signed_in
        end
    end
end

describe "GET 'index'" do
    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        it "should deny access" do
            get :index
            response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
            flash[:notice].should =~ /sign in/i
        end
    end

    describe "for signed-in users" do
        before(:each) do
            @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
            second = Factory(:user, :email => "another@example.com")
            third = Factory(:user, :email => "another@example.net")
            @users = [@user, second, third]
            30.times do
                @users << Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))
            end
        end

        it "should be successful" do
            get :index
            response.should be_success
        end

        it "should have the right title" do
            get :index
            response.should have_selector("title", :content => "All users")
        end

        it "should have an element for each user" do
            get :index
            @users[0..2].each do |user|
                response.should have_selector("li", :content => user.name)
            end
        end

        it "should paginate users" do
            get :index
            response.should have_selector("div.pagination")
            response.should have_selector("span.disabled", :content => "Previous")
            response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?escape=false&poge=2", :content => "2")
            response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?escape=false&page=2", :content => "Next")
        end
    end
describe "GET 'edit'" do
    before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
        test_sign_in(@user)
    end

    it "should be successful" do
        get :edit, :id => @user
        response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
        get :edit, :id => @user
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
    end

    it "should have a link to change the Gravatar" do
        get :edit, :id => @user
        gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/emails"
        response.should have_selector("a", :href => gravatar_url, :content => "change")
    end
end

describe "PUT 'update'" do
    before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
        test_sign_in(@user)
    end

    describe "failure" do
        before(:each) do
            @attr = {:email => "", :name => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => ""}
        end

        it "should render the 'edit' page" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
            response.should render_template('edit')
        end

        it "should have the right title" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
            response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
        end
    end

    describe "success" do
        before(:each) do
            @attr = {:name => "New Name", :email => "user@example.org", :password => "barbaz", :password_confirmation => "barbaz"}
        end

        it "should change the user's attributes" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
            @user.reload
            @user.name.should == @attr[:name]
            @user.email.should == @attr[:email]
        end

        it "should redirect to the user show page" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
            response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
        end

        it "should have a flash message" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
            flash[:success].should =~ /updated/
        end
    end
end

describe "authentication of edit/update pages" do
    before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
    end

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        it "should deny access to 'edit'" do
            get :edit, :id => @user
            response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
        end

        it "should deny access to 'update'" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
            :response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
        end
    end

    describe "for signed-in users" do
        before(:each) do
            wrong_user = Factory(:user, :email => "user@example.net")
            test_sign_in(wrong_user)
        end

        it "should require matching users for 'edit'" do
            get :edit, :id => @user
            response.should redirect_to(root_path)
        end

        it "should require matching users for 'update'" do
            put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
            response.should redirect_to(root_path)
        end
    end
end
end
end
```

Comment: Which version of the tutorial are you doing? What chapter are you on? Does the app work?  Seeing the spec files would help.  :)

Comment: I'm on chapter 10 of the 3.0 version. The app does work - I'm updating the question above, so just give me one sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

poge should be page

```
response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?escape=false&poge=2", :content => "2")
```

Join the rest of us in the boneheaded mistake gang.

Comment: I have forgotten the face of my father. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a guess that you may not have included a test_sign in method on your rspec tests to authenticate your test users before going to the show action etc. See this section for details
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec:requiring_signed_in_users

Comment: I was able to resolve most of my issues with the tests (it was a bonehead mistake like I thought) but I still have one more - let me update in a minute here.